# How can I get more saved-game slots in Portal 2?

Tags: portal-2

I'm playing Portal 2 (Windows XP version), in chapter 5.  When I try to save, the game tells me there are no saved-game slots left, and I will have to delete some saved games.  I find this behavior incredibly irritating.  Is there some way I can get more room for saved games?

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you can do what you ask, but unless you want to keep saves to access extremely specific parts of levels, you really don't need any more saves. Once you've finished a level you can always go back to it afterwards and play it again. So if there are some puzzles you like, you can skip straight to them (or to the beginning of the chapter, anyway).

Addendum from comments: Remember, you can always quicksave (F5) and quickload (F9), which is much faster. But you always overwrite your previous quicksave, so be aware of that. However, due to the design of the game it's essentially impossible to lose any progress short of a complete wipe of your saves.

Comment: The issue is not so much wanting to play old levels as it is wanting to be able to save frequently.   Going back to delete old saved games is Not Fun.

Comment: You can quicksave with F5 and then quickload with F9

Comment: Yeah, why on earth aren't you just quicksaving...?

Answer (score 2):

You can save over previous save slots - if you find you run out just keep some useful ones.

Remember you shouldn't need very many - only enough to complete a single level, then maybe again to get the achievements you missed first time around.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to your Steam installation. On Windows, the default installation directory is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam` for 64-bit editions. Otherwise, the default install location is `C:\Program Files\Steam`. In the Steam directory, go to `\steamapps\common\Portal 2\portal2\SAVE`, which contains a folder containing your saves. Copy the saves (.sav files) to another location. Open the game and delete some or all of the saves manually through the menus.

If you run out of saves again and you only deleted some, not all, of your saves last time, keep in mind that when you copy the files (if you copy *all* of the .sav files) to another location you will have some files which are duplicates of the some others you copied before.

Finally, provided there are enough save spaces available, you can copy or move save files which you copied from `\steamapps\common\Portal 2\portal2\SAVE` previously back into the folder inside this directory to load old saves in game.